# How to add a custom screen having an anchor/hyperlink and a textbox to enter some value by user before the welcome screen

Tags: templates, installation, project, visual-studio-setup-proje

How to add a custom screen having an anchor/hyperlink and a textbox to enter some value by user with a button before the welcome screen in intaller wizard in .Net Setup Project for creating the installer?

I am creating an installer to install a windows application using the "Setup Project" inside Visual Studio Installer templates. I want the customized screen as a very first screen as described below.

I want a screen before the "Welcome" screen during the intallation of an application, that has an anchor/hyperlink and a textbox for entering some value by user and a button to be clicked by user to get the input validated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for doing this in Visual Studio Setup Projects. The main issues are:

1. That dialog form sounds like a custom form of your own design. There is no support for custom forms in VS setup projects. The only extra dialogs are those pre-designed ones that you add using "Add Dialog" on the Start node in the UI view in the setup project.
2. There is no support for validation on button click in any of these dialogs. Using other tools you can run a custom action on button click, but the custom actions supported in VS setups all run at the end of the install after the files have been installed.

It might help if you described the problem you're trying to solve, because the question is asking how to implement a solution to a requirement or problem that you've not described. For example, if this is some kind of configuration of the application maybe it can be done in the application itself when it first runs.